# Can programming websites be accepted for Google AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Are programming sites not getting AdSense approval?

I have a site with few articles. I intend to write more, but I looked around on the net and found out that programming and coding sites are not being accepted anymore. Is this true?

Comment: I was unable to confirm that programming sites were ineligible for Google Adsense from the searches that I did.  Where did you discover the information that leads you to believe this?  Please provide links by editing your question.

Comment: You can read [Google Adsense program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=fr&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=fr&utm_source=ww-fr-et-storefront_adsense&answer=48182).

Answer (score 1):

If your website is all about programming codes, then it might be a hard task getting an Adsense approval. Instead, if your website is all about various programming practices, tips, advices, or even a knowledge base, it shall get approved soon.

Read through the Adsense guidelines to get an idea.